# What component models are available on my machine?

Tags: linux

I would like to know what [component models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component-based_software_engineering) (e.g. [CORBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture), [D-Bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus), [UNO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Network_Objects), [XPCOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPCOM), [ActiveX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX), [COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model), etc.) are installed on my machine.

Is there a command that I can run on the terminal to see a list of the different component models available?

Answer (score 0):

I believe [ActiveX](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1739297) and [COM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3063321/200908) are windows only. I'm not familiar with UNO, but reading the Wikipedia article suggests that it is available on Linux. You'd have to install the [LibreOffice SDK](http://api.libreoffice.org/docs/install.html) to work with it. If you've installed that SDK, you'd have UNO.

Comment: That's correct. OpenOffice and LibreOffice use UNO. Since I have LibreOffice installed, I know for a fact that UNO is available on my system. However, I would like to know if there is a command that I can run on the terminal that lists the different component models that are available on my system. As a side note, I included ActiveX and COM only to provide more examples of component models.

Comment: I think on general principles there wouldn't be one command to list all component models. You'd probably have to have an idea of what you're looking for and search for it.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Full answer: There is not a system level command to list installed/available component model(s).